# Bluetooth Microphone Access Denied Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, microphone, headset

Im trying to record áudio from a Bluetooth Headset ( Plantronics M-70) using a Windows phone 8.1 but Im getting Access Denied!! . I can redirect to other internal phone microphone and it Works well. Do I need to pass device to a Bluetooth Object first? Any suggestion will be helpfull. See exemple code below Im using to try this :

```
     string devID = "";
    var dev = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
    foreach (DeviceInformation mic in dev)
    {
        if (mic.Id.Contains("9980b050")) // Bluetooth Headset
        {
            devID = mic.Id;
        }
     }                }

    _mediaCaptureManager = new MediaCapture();
    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    settings.AudioDeviceId = devID;
    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
    settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other;                   await _mediaCaptureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

....

```
 MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
IStorageFile stre =  await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(@"hellohello.wav",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await _mediaCaptureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, stre);
```

.....

( Bluetooth Headset)

.AudioDeviceId = "\\?\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.1.00000000}.{9980b050-f8ca-4118-9234-bc92629f64be}#{2eef81be-33fa-4800-9670-1cd474972c3f}"

But Im having a Exception at mediaCapture_Failed Handler : Access Denied, with code:2147942405

Im setting previlegies to in Package Manifest:

```
Capability Name="internetClientServer" 
Capability Name="picturesLibrary" 
Capability Name="musicLibrary"
DeviceCapability Name="microphone" 
DeviceCapability Name="proximity"
```

I dont see other access previlegies I can give to Bluetooth.
I just want to save microphone data and using MediaCapture redirected.
I notice my MS that we have to put .InitializeAsync(settings) in MainPage main UI to user give rights for use of microphone. I did this but still not working for Bluetooth.

Thank you in Advance for any help
Lopes